# Maps with Clipping on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, clip, transparency-opacity, masking

We are publishing raster layers (computed via kriging) to ArcGIS server 10.1. A significant feature of our local geography is a large body of water, in our case, Lake Michigan.

Although I can clip the raster layer to exclude the water on ArcGIS Desktop, I get an error message: 000026 Data frames with a clip shape are not supported.

Because of this, the raster layer "bleeds" into the water. The result is not pleasant.  How can I effect "clipping" and still publish to the ArcGIS server?

P.S. I considered some kind of a mask, to block out the lake. But it seems that the transparency setting is for the whole layer, and so might block out the lake, but also cover up the land.)

Comment: This is an [**ArcGIS Online solution**](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/05/02/masking-arcgis-online-web-maps/) for masking raster layers using a feature service but maybe you can adapt it to your ArcGIS Server and client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clip dataframe by shape is not supporting for MapService because of the performance. So the performance reason, you would better to clip the raster data source directly. I guess you have Spatial Analyst extension license, then you could use "Extract by Mask" tool.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000

Hope this help you.

Comment: helps a lot.  Quick question, what is the difference between clipping and masking?  Sound very similar.  Is it because the exact shape is already determined in masking, but clip by shape has to do a lot more work?

Comment: @EricBrown clip and mask is same.  This meaning is not important. If you apply "Clip by shape" to dataframe, It must calculate visible area for every rendering phase. This costs a lot of time, so ArcGIS Server does not supporting it. But if you clip the raster by using "Extract by Mask" tool beforehand,  the raster datasource is already clipped, So You can publish MapSerive without applying "Clip by shape".